# Wordpress - Record in the db, data obtained from json

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I wrote this plugin that perfectly receives and shows data from an external API.

Code:

```
function get_posts_via_rest() {

    $request = wp_remote_get( 'http://xxx' );
    if( is_wp_error( $request ) ) {
        return false; // Bail early
    }
    $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request );
    $risposta_json = json_decode( $body );
    //print_r($data);

    if( ! empty( $risposta_json ) ) {

        foreach($risposta_json->data->offerte->data as $offerta ){ // now iterate through that array
            if($offerta->struttura->id == aggancio_id_campo_uno()){ // check all conditions
                echo '<ul>';
                echo '<li>'.$offerta->struttura->nome .'</li>';
                echo '<li>'.$offerta->struttura->url_completo .'</li>';
                echo '<li>'.$offerta->titolo .'</li>';
                echo '</ul>';
            }

        }

    }
}

// Register as a shortcode to be used on the site.
add_shortcode( 'sc_get_posts_via_rest', 'get_posts_via_rest' );
```

Now I have created a type of custom post called bids, as this code shows all the bids for a given company id, which is set with an input field that I didn't put here because it was superfluous, my question is how do I now have the data from json to register them inside the db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May this  help you:

```
global $wpdb;
$table = $wpdb->prefix.'you_table_name';
$data = array('column1' => 'data one', 'column2' => 123);
$format = array('%s','%d');
$wpdb->insert($table,$data,$format);
$my_id = $wpdb->insert_id;
```

Comment: two questions: in the table posts-> guid, the url of the post is generated, how can I generate it?

how can I with an if loop, say if the result you are about to register in the table has already been registered, then don't register?